# ui-router optional, unknown number of state params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to define state with unknown stateParams, example:
http://host/products?cat1=a&cat2=b&cat44=y&....
The number of stateParameters is unknown.
How can I define such url and how I can redirect to it?

```
.state('producs', {
                url: "/products/?magic",
                controller: 'ProductsController',
            })
```

...

```
$state.go($state.current, magicQueryParams, {});
```

Comment: Have you tried angular.fromJson and just use the string?

Comment: please give an example. In addition I need history support